# How to create an additional YAML file for Swagger UI instead of a replacing one?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I have 2 Spring profiles. There's one difference between them that I need to have included in my Swagger UI.

These profiles use a different server. I have `@OpenApiDefinition` with a bunch of lines of configuration. There, I can specify `servers`, but I'd have to maintain 2 different Java classes that are pretty much the same with the only difference in servers.

Instead I could specify a YAML file with `servers` and enable it only for the profile I want it to have (in `application-${profile}.properties`). It'd make the code much cleaner.

Can I do that? Or maybe there's some other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a library like Springdoc or Springfox, you can define an  [`OpenAPI`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/latest/io/swagger/v3/oas/models/OpenAPI.html) bean:

```java
@Bean
public OpenAPI openAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .servers(List.of(
            new Server().url("http://my-url")
        ))
        // ... Rest of configuration
}
```

All the configuration you put in the `@OpenApiDefinition` annotation, can also be put within this object.

This also allows you to configure the URL (and other properties) through properties. For example:

```java
@Bean
public OpenAPI openAPI(@Value("${openapi.server}") String server) {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .servers(List.of(
            new Server().url(server)
        ))
        // ... Rest of configuration
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed with one little change. I created a `defaultOpenAPIDefinition` private method that returns the intersection between both of the beans (what you have marked in code examples as `// ... Rest of configuration`. So: first I get the intersection of both profile's documentation i.e. `defaultOpenApiDefinition()` and then I add customized information about servers for both of them. Thanks!